# Using Chrome remote debugging for sending 'Enter' key

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am using Chrome remote debugging protocol in a Chrome extension is order to send keyboard events to a page. This is working well for standard input, but I am failing to find the right parameters to pass in order to create an 'Enter' key event. I am working on Windows.
Here is the link to the protocol:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/protocol/1.1/input

I am aware that I can do it using plain JavaScript and KeyboardEvent (in a content-script) but this is not a valid solution for my needs. 
Anyone did it before and succeeded?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I figured it out...
Here are the events that should be send:

```
{
    "type" : "rawKeyDown",
    "windowsVirtualKeyCode" : 13,
    "unmodifiedText" : "\r",//This is the critical part
    "text" : "\r" //This is the critical part
}
```

Then the same event with type = "char" and "keyUp".

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with @Yehuda's answer and reducing, I found that a single

```
{
    "type" : "char",
    "text" : "\r"
}
```

worked.